# How to prevent my phonegap app from working after blocking my phone

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have in my app a timer which counts from 10 to 0 and on 0 turns music on. Works good but after blocking my phone or when my app starts to work in the background after clicking this button[image] my timer is still going. The result is that when I switch my app to the another one after few seconds my music starts to play. Same when I block my app. My app doesn't stop. And my question is: Is there any cordova plugin to set my app in 'background mode' or when the phone is blocked? I could block then my timer or something but first something must detect this behaviour.